# change the pointer referenced variable in a function

Tags: c, pointers

I have created a pointer variable to point to an active variable.
I have two variables, I want to toggle the active variable between these two variables.
Managed to do this inside the main. Now I want to extend this to another function

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int *active=&y;

    if(active == &x)
       active = &y;
    else
       active = &x;

}
```

I dont want to swap the values of the variables, x, y.

x, y are coordinates of a cartesian plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the reference of the pointer variable to the function, and in the formal parameter list create a pointer which holds the memory address of the pointer variable

```
void flip(int **act, int *x, int *y){
    if(*act == x){
        *act = y;
    }else{
        *act = x;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int *active=&y;

    flip(&active, &x, &y);

}
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `void flip(int **act, int *x, int *y)`?

Comment: Can you please submit you answer as well ?
Here I have passed the reference of the pointer variable to the function

Comment: @NuOne, you have passed *a pointer to* the pointer variable to function `flip`.  C does not have references.  You have also passed pointers to `main`'s local `x` and `y` variables.  But the types of those arguments do not match the declared type's of `flip()`'s parameters, so the program has undefined behavior.  Your compiler should at least be warning about that.  If it isn't, then either turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.  Your program might happen to work correctly on some systems, with some compilers, but it will definitely malfunction on others.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you suggest an answer

Comment: @NuOne, Dmitri already told you how to correct your code.  No other change is required.